# Socket.Receive() stuck

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm practicing my C# after having missed out on it in about two years and writing a client for a server. Anyways, the problem is that Socket.Receive() seems to be stuck (my loop doesn't actually get through, tested it).. Here's my call in Program.cs:

```
                byte[] buffer = new byte[7];
                hSocket.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 500);
```

And here's the snippet of my APISocket.cs

```
        public bool Connect(string ServerIP, int ServerPort, int Timeout)
        {
            TimeoutObject.Reset();
            SocketException = null;
            try
            {
                Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), ServerPort);
                object state = new object();
                Socket.BeginConnect(IPEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(CallBackMethod), state);
```

```
            if (TimeoutObject.WaitOne(Timeout, false))
            {
                if (IsConnected)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            SocketException = Ex;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void CallBackMethod(IAsyncResult AsyncResult)
    {
        try
        {
            IsConnected = false;

            if (Socket.Connected)
            {
                IsConnected = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            SocketException = Ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            TimeoutObject.Set();
        }
    }



    public void Receive(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
    {
        SocketException = null;
        int startTick = Environment.TickCount;
        int received = 0;

        do
        {
            if (Environment.TickCount > startTick + timeout)
            {
                SocketException = new Exception("Timeout.");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                received += Socket.Receive(buffer, offset + received, size - received, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            catch (SocketException Ex)
            {
                if (Ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                    Ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                    Ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                }
                else
                {
                    SocketException = Ex;
                    return;
                }
            }
        } while (received < size);
    }
```

I have no idea where I'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated..

Comment: are you sure the server is listening? what does the socket initialization code look like?

Comment: Yes. I'm emulating a launcher for a login server, and it works with the old launcher. I know my packets are correct, the socket is initialized asynchronously, could that be a problem?

Comment: what do you mean by async init? that could be a problem, yes.

Comment: i'm building the connection of my socket asynchronously, that is what i meant.

Comment: add that code in. if i remember correctly, doing so the wrong way can lead to what you're describing.

Comment: alright, just added it!

Answer (score 0):

`Socket.Receive()` is a blocking call.  If there is no data available it will block until there is data available to read.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26f591ax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

`If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using Socket.ReceiveTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Receive call will throw a SocketException.`

Comment: What if i send data and is still stuck on Receive like just ignores it?